# Swift - reset data after one month

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app which kind of sums up user input. This data is being stored. I want this user data to be reset to 0 after one month from the day he started using the app. After one month the `startDate` obviously shall be the day the data has been reset.

So far I have:

```
func checkIfClearData() {
    let startDate: Date = Date()
    var monthComponent = DateComponents()
    monthComponent.month = 1

    let theCalendar = Calendar.current
    let endDate = theCalendar.date(byAdding: monthComponent, to: startDate)
}
```

I'm stuck. How to include the `currentDate` and how do I properly use such function since it can solely be called once per month? Otherwise I reckon `endDate` will increase and never be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following to compare startDate with endDate

```
if Date().timeIntervalSince(endDate) < 0 {
    // endDate ahead
} else {
    // endDate expired
}
```

Example to get you started

```
class DataTimer {

    static var shared = DataTimer()

    var startDate: Date!
    var endDate: Date!

    private init() {
        check()
    }

    func check() {
        guard
            let startDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "kStartDate") as? Date,
            let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: startDate)
        else {
            self.resetDates()
            return
        }

        var interval = Date().timeIntervalSince(endDate)
        guard interval < 0 else {
            self.resetUserData()
            self.resetDates()
            return
        }

        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = endDate

        // log remaining time
        interval = abs(interval)
        let log: [Int] = [86400.0, 3600.0, 60.0].map { value in
            guard interval > value else { return 0 }

            let returnValue = Int(floor(interval / value))
            interval.formTruncatingRemainder(dividingBy: value)
            return returnValue
        }
        print("Remaining: \(log[0])d \(log[1])h \(log[2])m \(Int(interval))s")
    }

    private func resetUserData() { }

    private func resetDates() {
        self.startDate = Date()
        self.endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: startDate)!
        UserDefaults.standard.set(startDate, forKey: "kStartDate")
    }
}
```

**Usage-1**

```
DataTimer.shared.check()
```

**Usage-2** each time app start/enter-foreground in `AppDelegate.swift`

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    DataTimer.shared.check()
}
```

Comment: You can also just compare 2 dates directly: (`if Date() > endDate`)

Answer (score 1):

When the app launches, check a key (e.g "startingDate") in UserDefaults.

If it's nil, save the current date to that key.

If it's not nil, read it. Compare the saved date and today's date. If the amount of time elapsed is < 1 month, read the stored data as usual. If the amount of time elapsed is >= 1 month, delete all the stored data and then save today's date to the key in UserDefaults to start over.